# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element

Tags: xml, xsd

**Got** [Invalid content] **error**:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found
>       starting with element 'AGMT_NUMBER'
>       One of '{'http://www.mycompany.com/xmlns/commonDefintions":AGMT_NUMBER}'
>       is expected.

I have two `xsd` files which are suppose to validate following `xml` file

**`myFile.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TEST_FILE>
    <ROW>
         <AGMT_NUMBER>1234</AGMT_NUMBER>
    </ROW>
</TEST_FILE>
```

This is my first xsd **`Main.XSD`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   
  xmlns:common="http://www.mycompany.com/xmlns/commonDefintions"  
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:import schemaLocation="common.xsd" 
      namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/xmlns/commonDefintions"/>
    <xs:element name="TEST_FILE">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element ref="common:A"></xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This is the xsd I am referring from **`common.xsd`**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com/xmlns/commonDefintions" 
   xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/xmlns/commonDefintions" 
   elementFormDefault="qualified">


    <xs:element name="A" type="AgmtInfo"></xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="AgmtInfo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AGMT_NUMBER" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: The schema you've shown isn't remotely consistent with the instance document, there's no declaration of `TEST_FILE` or `ROW` elements anywhere in the schema so validation should have failed well before it got to the `AGMT_NUMBER`

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake when writing this up. Thanks for pointing that out, I have what you see above and it still fails. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The XML instance you show cannot possibly produce the error message you reproduce:  the error message shows that the validator encountered an element named AGMT_NUMBER in the namespace `http://www.mycompany.com/xmlns/commonDefintions`, but the AGMT_NUMBER element in your sample input is not in any namespace.  Ignoring that, in the instance, TEST_FILE has a child named AGMT_NUMBER; the schema says TEST_FILE has a single child named common:A.  What is it you don't understand here?